# How to go from c1*e^(wit) + c2*e^(-wit) into c1*cos(wt)+c2*sin(wt)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-number-e

So, I'm trying to prove the solution of
$$ \ddot{x} + b\dot{x} + cx = 0 $$
I have successfully done it for when the root $b^2 - 4c $ is positive or 0, but am now struggling to get it for negative roots.
So far, I have
$$ \lambda = \frac{-b}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2} = \frac{-b}{2} \pm i*\frac{\sqrt{4c-b^2}}{2} $$
I now set variables:
$$ \delta = \frac{-b}{2} $$
$$ w = \frac{\sqrt{4c-b^2}}{2} $$

And set those in for a solution:
$$ x(t) = c_1*e^{\delta t + wit}  + c_2 * e^{\delta t - wit} $$
We can factorize out $e^{\delta t} $, and we get:
$$ x(t) = e^{\delta t} (c_1*e^{wit} - c_2*e^{wit}) $$
Now, the solution is supposed to be
$$ x(t) = e^{\delta t}(c_1 * cos(wt) + c_2 * sin(wt)) $$ but I'm struggling converting it into that. I have tried using Eulers formula, but so far just gotten a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. So far you have

$$
x(t) = e^{\delta t} (c_1 e^{i \omega t} + c_2 e^{-i \omega t})
$$

now use Euler's identity

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& e^{\delta t}\left(c_1(\cos \omega t + i\sin \omega t) + c_2(\cos \omega t - i \sin \omega t)\right) \\
&=& e^{\delta t}\left(\underbrace{(c_1 + c_2)}_{a_1}\cos \omega t + \underbrace{i (c_1 - c_2)}_{a_2}\sin \omega t\right) \\
&=& e^{\delta t}(a_1 \cos \omega t + a_2 \sin \omega t)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Ahh shit thanks, actually got to the almost-last expression, but then the i was in the way. Factoring it in the constant makes so much more sense.